# how do i call dictionary values from within a list of dictionaries ?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i am trying to learn python with codeacademy. 
the assignment was make 3 dictionaries (for each student) and then make a list of the 3 dictionaries. then, i am supposed to print out all the data in the list.

i tried to call out the values the same way i used for a dictionary by itself (lloyd[values]), but then it says that values is not defined o_O. I have also tried to 'print names' but then the error message is that i didn't print out one of the values.

i'd appreciate your help very much.

```
 lloyd = {
     "name": "Lloyd",
     "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
     "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
     "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
 }
 alice = {
     "name": "Alice",
     "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
     "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
     "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
 }
 tyler = {
     "name": "Tyler",
     "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
     "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
     "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
 }
 students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
 for names in students:
     print lloyd[values]
```

Comment: `values` is not defined; it is not a variable you can pass to `lloyd[...]`. Did you mean `names.values()` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print all the information for each student, you have to loop over the students and the values stored in the dictionaries:

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
for student in students:
    for value in student:
        print value, "is", student[value]
```

Note, however, that dictionaries are not ordered, so the order of the values might not be the way you want it. In this case, print them individually, using the name of the value as a string as key:

```
for student in students:
    print "Name is", student["name"]
    print "Homework is", student["homework"]
    # same for 'quizzes' and 'tests'
```

Finally, you could also use the `pprint` module for "pretty-printing" the student dictionaries:

```
import pprint
for student in students:
    pprint.pprint(student)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply print the values of the dicts:

```
for names in students:
   print names #names are the dictionaries
```

If you want to print just the names, then use the `name` key:

```
for student in students:
    print student['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using namedtuple instead for readability and scalability:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', ['name', 'hw', 'quiz', 'test'])

Alice = Student('Alice', herHWLst, herQuizLst, herTestLst)
Ben = Student('Ben', hisHWLst, hisQuizLst, hisTestLst)

students = [Alice, Ben]

for student in students:
    print student.name, student.hw[0], student.quiz[1], student.test[2] 
    #whatever value you want
```

If you really want to create tons of dictionaries, you can read it with your code above by:

```
for student in students:
    name = student['name']
    homeworkLst = student['homework']
    # get more values from dict if you want
    print name, homeworkLst
```

Accessing dictionary is super fast in Python, but creating them may not be as fast and efficent. The namedtuple is more practical in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So `students` is a list of dictionaries. You then want

```
for student in students:
    print student['name']
```

Also when you want to call a key in a dictionary you have to put the key name in quotes, as a string: `alice[homework]` doesn't work because Python thinks `homework` is a variable. You need `alice['homework']` instead.

So to look at all of the information nicely, you could do

```
for student in students:
    for field in student.keys():
        print "{}: {}".format(field, student[field])
```

You can play around to make the formatting nicer, e.g. printing name first, inserting a new line between each new student, etc.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved mine on codeacademy. Hope someone finds this helpful
for student in students:

```
print student['name']
print student['homework']
print student['quizzes']
print student['tests']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got them to accept.

```
for name in students:
    print name["name"]
    print name["homework"]
    print name["quizzes"]
    print name["tests"]
```

This also works but they would not accept.

```
for name in students:
    print name
```